# Pattern for Creating Recurring Events

Tags: design-patterns

Every now and then I face some feature that would be better if I put some recurring hability in it.

To make it clear let me use a known example. In Google Calendar, when I set an event as recurring let´s say every monday, it will show it every Monday. I can keep rolling the weeks forward and it will show the event.

I don´t really believe that they create the event in the database for every monday until the eternity :-), nor they create it until some far far away year.

I´d like to know if there´s some well known pattern for doing such a thing or any guide with best practices.

Thank You.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, Martin Fowler has the definitive word on [how to describe recurrences](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) from a data modelling point of view. Once you've captured recurrences, you just need to provide code to retrieve events for a given date(time).

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been dead for awhile, but I was searching for an answer; something simple that would handle all the most common approaches. Specifically, how to store these dates in an relational database.

I'm considering, but haven't implemented the following solution:

### Table: Schedule

Id

Name

StartDate

EndDate

DayOfYear (Can be any sequence of numbers from 1-365)

DayOfMonth (Can by any sequence of numbers from 1-31)

Month (Any sequence of 1-12)

DayOfWeek (Any sequence of 1-7)

WeekOfMonth (Any sequence of 1-5)

SkipInterval (smallint)

Excluding (Many2Many Relationship back to this table)

### Examples:

Where all other values are Nil.

Labor Day: StartDate = 9/1/2013, DayOfWeek = 2 (Monday), Month = 9, WeekOfMonth = 1

Valentine's Day: StartDate = 2/14/2013, DayOfMonth = 14, Month = 2

Every Third Friday of Each Month: StartDate = 9/20/2013, DayOfWeek = 6, WeekOfMonth = 3

Every Other Friday: StartDate = 10/4/2013; DayOfWeek = 6, SkipInterval = 2

Every Week Day: StartDate = 10/4/2013; DayOfWeek = 2-6

Every Day: StartDate = 10/4/2013

Every Monday: StartDate = 10/7/2013, DayOfWeek = 2

Excludes can be used to remove all Holidays from an event schedule. (Nobody is going to work out on Thanksgiving, right?), assuming all Holidays have been entered.

Comment: Valentine's day is 2/14